# How to replace a navbar with a search div when scrolling down in VueJS3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

I am new to `vuejs`, I am trying to make my `search component` to replace my `fixed-top` navbar when the `searchdiv` hit the top of the screen while scrolling down, and when I scroll up, the navbar will only appear when the user is on top. I have seen this kind of functionaliy like google search. please see:

This is the normal view:
[image]

This is the scrolled view:
[image]

and this is mine:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
  created() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("HomeLandingComponent mounted");
  },
  methods: {

    handleScroll() {
      let scrollY = window.scrollY
      if (scrollY > this.startY) {
        this.navbar_visible = false;
      } else {
        this.navbar_visible = true;
      }
      this.startY = scrollY;
    }
  }
```

what is does is just basically hide the navbar when scroll down and show navbar on scroll up. Is there a way on how to achieve it?

Comment: Your best bet may be to experiment with some Vue frameworks, such as [Quasar](https://quasar.dev/) or [Vuetify](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/) rather than try to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.
Ensure that the search bar comes after the navbar and that the search bar is not nested; then on the search bar, position fixed; z-index: 1; you can use JavaScript to add a new class to give background a new colour.
Shouldn't be too hard. I'll write the code once I'm on my PC.